# How to send multipart/form-data request with Basic Authentication via postman?

Tags: rest, postman

A provider provides content type as `multipart/form-data` data and authorization like this `Basic  Base64encodedValueOf(client_id:client_secret)`. How to do this in postman?

```
  {
  "customer_identifier": "customer@corporate.in",
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "aadhaar_offline",
      "title": "Offline KYC",
      "description": "Please authenticate using Aadhaar to retrieve offline xml from UIDAI"
    }
  ],
  "unique_reference_id": "CRN122306114425315NN"
}
```

Comment: Did it provide you username and password?

Comment: no . they given like this Headers : 
       Authorization : “Basic  Base64encodedValueOf(client_id:client_secret)” 
       Content-Type :   multipart/form-data

Comment: maybe you need to ask them

Answer (score 0):

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44ZmY.jpg)> add url

> if it have auth use headers and insert creditendials

Comment: i already tried what you are said but not getting .it is a  multipart/form-data not json/application

Answer (score 0):

For adding a Base64 Auth Header:

- Select the `Authorization` tab
- Select `Basic Auth`
- Add the Client Id and Secret values
- Select `Preview Request`

Once you have done this, you will see the new header under the `Headers` tab.

[image: Postman Auth 1]

These can also be added to an environment, global or collection level variable so you're not hardcoding these into those fields.

[image: Postman Auth 2]

Comment: {
    "details": "EX2002131720205008I8",
    "message": "Unsupported media type",
    "code": "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE"
}

Comment: Without knowing more about the requests your making or the API you're hitting, that error doesn't mean a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

For the **Authorization Header: Basic Base64encodedValueOf(client_id:client_secret)** part where you have the `client_id` and `client_secret`, you can

- go to the **Authorization** tab
- choose **Basic Auth** type of Authorization
- enter the `client_id` in Username, `client_secret` in the Password.

Basically, same as answered by [Danny Dainton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6028443/danny-dainton).

For **Content-Type : multipart/form-data**, you need to

- go to the **Body** tab
- select **form-data**
- here one **key** would be `request`, where you would have to enter the complete JSON text as **value** (the one you have posted in your question).
- the other **key** would be `file`, here, you will have to change the key type from **Text** to **File** (look for a dropdown on hover of the key field), then for **value** choose the file you want to upload, using **Select File** option.

Please confirm the key names with the API Documentation of your Provider.